# Angular Dialog Background White

Tags: css, angular

The background is only showing white by default, are there any CSS codes that I can force it to blur or darken the background instead? I've tried using CSS but I was unable to find the class it was called, I've put the "hasBackdrop" attribute to false as well but it didn't affect anything.

[image: Current Display]

CSS Code

```
::ng-deep .mat-dialog-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

p {
    color: black;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>test-modal works!</p>
```

Code to call the modal

```
export class CallModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openTestModal() {
    this.dialog.open(TestModalComponent, {
      hasBackdrop: false
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a classes to change the dialog backgrounds or the backdrop by provide it as custom class in open config paramter

```js
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialog,{
  backdropClass:'backdrop-bg-orange',
  panelClass:'bg-blue'
});
```

*style.scss*

```css
.bg-blue .mat-dialog-container{
  background: lightblue;
}

.backdrop-bg-orange {
 background: orange;
}
```

> it 's important to put the classes in the **global style file** , it will not work if you add the classes to component template because angular update all component style to work just for the current component ([ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation))

[*****stackblitz demo*****](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matdialog-theme?file=src/app/dialog-content-example.ts)

Comment: Your code turns the background to orange, alright. Is there a way to have transparent background. I want the content of original page to be visible with a transparent backdrop. How can I do that.? Changing orange to transparent doesn't wrk/

Comment: Did you find out solution ?